# jquery the parameter passed in is null when set form action attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set my form action to another page with a parameter in url using code below:

```
ui.setFormActionToTargetPage = function () {
    $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'myTargetPage.html?id='+id);
};
```

My html page is like

```
<form class="form-horizontal row-border" data-validate="parsley" id="validate-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    <button class="btn-default" onclick="ui.setFormActionToTargetPage();">Cancel</button>  
    ...
</form>
```

However, I did get forwarded to myTargetPage.html but it seems the id parameter is not passed while some form content was passed as parameter 'text'. I verified that when setFormActionToTargetPage is called the url is as expected. However, when it hit the target page, the window.location.href is not correct, which is 'myTargetPage.html?text= some form content'. Anyone know why?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using 'id' in your logic but I don't see where you are passing it in or it is declared any where.

Comment: The default form method is ‘get’ and the default behavior of a button on a form is to submit the form when clicked, so what you’re seeing is the button click calling the javascript which sets the action, although id is undefined, and then the default button behavior kicks in and submits the form, replacing the querystring with your form fields (text=blah)

Comment: @James I verified when the js function kicks in, the id is set correctly. More specific, when the js set the action, it does give the correct url for the form action, e.g. myTargetPage.html?id=123. But when myTargetPage.html was hit, the id was not attached to the url but those text=blah thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the form method to post so the form data doesn't interfere with the querystring.  If you have your id value somewhere and it's working already then great, otherwise you can pass it through the button onclick call like this.

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal row-border" data-validate="parsley" id="validate-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <button class="btn-default" onclick="ui.setFormActionToTargetPage(123);">Cancel</button>  

</form>

ui.setFormActionToTargetPage = function (id) {
    $('form').prop('action', 'myTargetPage.html?id='+id);
};
```